# iOS: Unable to see the option of App Icon in the Product Page Optimization page in the app store connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ab-testing, appicon, abtest

As the **Product Page Optimization** option is now available in the App Store Connect, I thought to try it out.

So I have created a test to try different App Icons.
I have followed these steps to create a test and treatments for product page optimization,
https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev811bef199

But there I am unable to see the option to change the App Icon for different treatments.
There I can only see the screenshots, as you can see in the attached SS.[image]

Please let me know how can I get the option to change the App Icon for different treatments for Product Page Optimization.

Comment: I didn't try it yet but maybe after uploading an app with an alternate icon, you can see the icon options? Just a wild guess, I also have the same problem but I am using Unity, so my case is worse than yours :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your app binary must contain alternative icons, before you can use them in the Product Page Optimization page.

The simplest way to add alternative icons to your app is to add them in the Assets file of your app together with the `Include All App Icon Assets` build setting. It's important that each icon also include a large 1024pt file.

More tips how to add icons to your app can be found here: https://medium.com/@gianpispi/how-to-use-xcassets-for-alternative-icons-20849f836e2f

Comment: I followed the instructions, added alternative icons, verified it by successfully changing the icon on runtime, submitted to review, released the version but app icon tab on product page optimization still wont show up. do you know if there are additional steps required?

Comment: @fmog your issue may be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77350937/ios-alternative-icons-not-showing-in-the-appstore-connect#comment136579865_77350937.      Looks  like a bug on Apple's side. We have no solution yet.