# iOS Alternative Icons not showing in the AppStore Connect

Tags: ios, xcode

I have added alternative icons to the iOS app (Xcode 14.3.1):

1. I have all 1024x1024 PNGs in the asset catalog.
2. I have icons listed in `Alternate App Icon Sets`.
3. `Include All App Icon Assets` is enabled.
4. I checked that I can pick and set any of included icons as the primary one.
5. iOS Minimum Target is 15.0
6. After the build I can see my icons names in `CFBundleAlternateIcons` section of the the `Info.plist`.
7. I examined `Assets.car` archive withing the app bundle and it contains all icons.

But after uploading the build to App Store connect the Included Assets section of the Build lists only the primary icon.

And alternative icons are not available for Product Page Optimization even after the build was reviewed and published in the store.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is this your first build with the alt-icons? Is this going to TF, or straight to the store?

Comment: @benc First, it goes to TF then to the store manually. Yes, it is the first build with alt-icons.

Comment: I wish I had practical advice. It's one of those features I saw in the docs years ago, and had time to try. I know it works in the field, a couple apps like Slack are using it.

Comment: We have a very similar problem.
Our application had an alternative icon and it worked on the Product Optimization Page.
But around the spring of 2023, after the next update of our application, the icon stopped appearing on the Product Optimization Page.
This looks like a bug on Apple's side.

We tried many different fixes, they didn't work.
We want to try to update Xcode to 15.0.1, but we cannot update yet. Because to check it, you need to upload the application to the store, but we cannot yet upgrade the Xcode version for organizational reasons.

Comment: I've tried Xcode 15.0.1 it did not helped. Btw, when alternative icons are in the build should they be visible in "Included Assets" section of the app version info page in App Store Connect?

Comment: @AntonPetrov Our manager who works with App Store Connect said that even when alternative icon worked for us, it didnt appear in "Included Assets" section of the app version info page