# Alternative icon not showing on AppStoreConnect

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm trying to add alternative icons so I can run an A/B test on the AppStore (Product Page Optimisation). When I try to set up the test, the option for an icon is not there.

**Here's how it's supposed to look according to Apple:**

[image]

Here is what I've tried so far:

**Build settings - Asset Catalog Complier - Options**

1. Added "Alternate App Icon Sets" - `DarkIcon`
2. Marked "Include All App Icon Assets" as `Yes`
3. Set "Primary App Icon Set Name" - `LightIcon`

**General settings - App Icons and Launch Screen**

1. Set "App Icon" - `Debug: LightIcon + DarkIcon (iOS)` & `Release: LightIcon + DarkIcon (iOS)`
2. Ticked "Include all app icon assets"

Neither of these worked - Didn't show up on AppStoreConnect. Also, when I upload a build it shows only one icon under "Included Assets".

I tried to look for official docs, but couldn't find any...

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77350937/ios-alternative-icons-not-showing-in-the-appstore-connect#comment136579865_77350937) thread doesn't have a solution, but it is about the same issue. Could be bug on Apple's end.

Comment: Have you implemented [setAlternateIconName()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/2806818-setalternateiconname)?

Comment: I did not, is that necessary?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. Implement that and see if you get the icon option for the next build.

Answer (score 0):

In your AppStoreConnect, click on that one icon which is showing under "Included Assets", then you will be able to see other alternate icon by click on next icon ">"

Comment: Unfortunately, although it does appear there, I still don't see the option to run an A/B test... Any idea why?